# The action of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ on $T^1(\mathbb H)$ is transitive?

Tags: dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Let $\mathbb H$ to be the complex upper-half plane and let $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ act on $\mathbb H$ by

$$\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},$$

where $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb R).$

A book I am reading says $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ acts transitively on the unit tangent bundle $T^1(\mathbb H)$ (that the action is isometry is easy to verify).

But I don't know why the action is transitive. Say given the points $z_1,z_2$ and vectors
$v_i\in T^1_{x_i}(\mathbb H), i=1,2$ then I need to find $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb R),$ such that $\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ satisfies:

(1) $\phi(z_1)=z_2$; and

(2) $d\phi_{z_1}(v_1)=v_2$.

But I don't know how to realize this since it involves some nonlinear systems in $a,b,c,d$

Comment: Transitivity on $\mathbb{H}$ itself isn’t too hard to ascertain (use upper-triangular matrices applied at $i$). So all you need to do is consider the action of the matrices $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\-b & a\end{bmatrix}$ with $a^2+b^2=1$ on the unit circle of the tangent space to $\mathbb{H}$ at $i$ (a fixed point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgroup that fixes $z=i$ is defined by the rotation matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}
$$
For $\phi(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ in this subgroup, one can calculate $\phi'(i) = \cos(2\theta) - i \sin(2\theta)$ (I think, or something very close to that). It follows that as $\theta$ verifies, the linear transformations $d\phi_i : z \mapsto \phi'(i) z$ acts transitively on the unit circle, that is to say it acts transitively on $T^1_i(\mathbb H)$.

It's also not hard, given $z_0 \in \mathbb H$, to find $a,b,c,d$ so that $\phi(i)=z_0$. Thus, fixing any base vector in $T^1_i(\mathbb H)$, I can first rotate it by an appropriate rotation matrix, and then map it by $d\phi$, to get any vector in $T^1_{z_0}(\mathbb H)$. This implies transitivity on $T^1(\mathbb H)$.